# R: minimumifs with a condition

Tags: r, data.table

This is a sample data:

```
df <- data.table(cake = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, "c1", "c1", "c1", "c2", "c2", "c3", "c3", "c3", "c3"),  walk = c(183, 789, 753, 130, 126, 44, 325, 710, 307, 264, 708, 769, 742, 559, 181, 138));
```

I wish to add a column `final` in this data.table which is equal to column `walk` only if adjoining row entry in the column `cake` is unique, but if it isnt unique i.e. there are multiple items then take minimum off all the values and only display it for the top one, rest can be set to zero.

e.g. cake:final ::  1:183, 2:789,,, c1:264, c3:138...etc.

ideally this would be `final` column.

`final=c(183, 789, 753, 130, 126, 44, 325, 264, 0, 0, 708, 0, 181, 0, 0, 0)`

I have tried this code, but it is wrong.

```
df[, is_unique := !duplicated(cake)]
df[, cake_count := .N, by = cake]
df[, min_walk := ifelse(duplicated(cake), min(walk), walk)]
df[, final := ifelse(is_unique, min_walk, 0)]
```

I would appreciate if it can be done using data.table package. I believe data.table is works better with very large datasets.

The column `cake`

1. is ordered here, but it isn't ordered sometimes.
2. has both numbers and characters or mix of both.

The column `walk`

1. is always values.

Please also give me code for, if in future i need to repeat the minimum value for all the non unique entries rather than fixing them to zero.

**I need to apply it to a very large dataset around a million.
Hence the code needs to be very efficient.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df$goal = c(183, 789, 753, 130, 126, 44, 325, 264, 0, 0, 708, 0, 181, 0, 0, 0)

df[, result := c(min(walk), rep(0, .N - 1)), by = cake]
df
#     cake walk goal result
#  1:    1  183  183    183
#  2:    2  789  789    789
#  3:    3  753  753    753
#  4:    4  130  130    130
#  5:    5  126  126    126
#  6:    6   44   44     44
#  7:    7  325  325    325
#  8:   c1  710  264    264
#  9:   c1  307    0      0
# 10:   c1  264    0      0
# 11:   c2  708  708    708
# 12:   c2  769    0      0
# 13:   c3  742  181    138
# 14:   c3  559    0      0
# 15:   c3  181    0      0
# 16:   c3  138    0      0
```

Or for more control over the placement:

```
## put the min 2nd for groups
df[, result := fifelse(.N == 1 | seq_len(.N) == 2, min(walk), 0), by = cake]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gregor. Please can you also tell how do I control, if I wish to display the 264 in ```result``` in 9th row. i.e. value shouldn't appear in 1st but in second or third..

Comment: `c(min(walk), rep(0, .N - 1))` builds the response for groups with multiple rows by putting `min(walk)` first followed by `.N - 1` 0s. You could use, for example, `c(0, min(walk), rep(0, .N - 2))` to have a `0` first, then `min(walk)`, then `.N - 2` 0s. I would be wary of putting it 3rd as you may need to special handling if the group has only 2 rows... but you could add additional `if` conditions to check the length.

Comment: Alternately, you could add a row number within each `cake` group, `df[, i := 1:.N, by = cake]`, and use that to put the min wherever you want, `df[, result := if(.N == 1) walk else fifelse(i == 3, min(walk), 0), by = cake]`

Comment: You don't need the conditional, as long as you accept the inefficiency that `min` of a single value is an identity. `df[, result := c(min(walk), rep(0, .N - 1)), by = cake]`. (The `rep(0, .N-1)` is safe enough to return length-0 when `.N` is 1.)

Comment: @Onyambu For golf purposes sure. Though I guess the `if` isn't really needed `df[, result := c(min(walk), rep(0, .N - 1)), by = cake]` works just as well, or a more readable version of yours `df[, result := fifelse(seq_len(.N) == 1, min(walk), 0), by = cake]`

Comment: @r2evans thanks - just realized that as you were posting. My guess is `min()` is pretty darn quick on a length-1 input, probably comparable to the `if(.N == 1)` check.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor. one last question please. I wish 264 to be in 10th row, next to itself. rest everything zero. i.e. wherever the minimum appears.

Comment: `df[, result := fifelse(walk == min(walk), min(walk), 0), by = cake]`

Comment: this is coming out great. if i need sum instead of min in the above code which you just commented ```df[, result := fifelse(walk == min(walk), min(walk), 0), by = cake]```. sum to be displayed instead the minimum. placement same as the way it is wherever the minimum appears.

Comment: Look up the `?fifelse` help page - (it's the same syntax as base R's `ifelse()`) and I bet you can work it out. You just need to replace one of the `min(walk)`s with `sum(walk)`.

Comment: it'll work with this data, be careful with `x == min(x)` though due to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272 when numbers are high-precision.

Comment: Yes, `which.min` would probably be safer (as long as taking the first tie is okay). Though, in general, I've not run into precision issues with `min` and `max` as they are copying values, not doing any computation. (Not to say it's fully robust.)

Comment: I have now tested it, purpose solved. However, the run time is bothering me. my data is around 1m. Actually earlier I was doing aggregation and then doing sum or min. but i prefer not to aggregate and keep all the rows. Aggregation using data.table was far more efficient than what I have done now.

Comment: Can anything be done to make the code run quicker?

Comment: It should be pretty quick. If you need to squeeze more performance out of it I would suggest asking another question focused on that, and provide simulated data of about the same size as your real data to benchmark on. What will be fastest on 16 rows with 10 groups may not be the fastest with 1M rows and ? groups.

Comment: The only way I can think to speed this up much is to make sure `min` or `which.min` is only called once, perhaps using a helper function like `min_at_min = function(x) {
  if(length(x) == 1L) return(x)
  wm = which.min(x)
  res = rep(0, length(x))
  res[wm] = x[wm]
  return(res)
}` and then running `df[, result := min_at_min(walk), by = cake]`. But perhaps someone will come up with something faster if you post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```r
df[,minwalk:=min(walk),by="cake"][minwalk!=walk,walk:=0][,minwalk:=NULL][order(cake,-walk)]
#>     cake walk
#>  1:    1  183
#>  2:    2  789
#>  3:    3  753
#>  4:    4  130
#>  5:    5  126
#>  6:    6   44
#>  7:    7  325
#>  8:   c1  264
#>  9:   c1    0
#> 10:   c1    0
#> 11:   c2  708
#> 12:   c2    0
#> 13:   c3  138
#> 14:   c3    0
#> 15:   c3    0
#> 16:   c3    0
```

Comment: i would like the code to work without ordering.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider multiplying the minimum with a bunch of 0's and 1's to remain with the final output:

```
df[,final := min(walk)*(seq_len(.N)==1), cake][]

    cake walk final
 1:    1  183   183
 2:    2  789   789
 3:    3  753   753
 4:    4  130   130
 5:    5  126   126
 6:    6   44    44
 7:    7  325   325
 8:   c1  710   264
 9:   c1  307     0
10:   c1  264     0
11:   c2  708   708
12:   c2  769     0
13:   c3  742   138
14:   c3  559     0
15:   c3  181     0
16:   c3  138     0
```